# How to open Excel file and bind data to it in C# MVC?

Tags: excel, epplus

I am writing a code in C# MVC using EPPlus.dll. I can export an Excel file. But, I want to read an Excel file from some path D drive or C drive or Virtual path. Which is having 5 rows of data already. Now, I want to bind another 50 rows continuous to those 5 rows in same Excel file.

I'm just using EPPlus dll. I don't have MS Office installed in my system. I have LibreOffice Calc (Open Source).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already reading a spreadsheet using EPPlus then you've got everything you need to append more rows to it.

The following sample shows how to open an existing spreadsheet, find the last row of data and add an additional 50 rows of data to it:

```
var file = new FileInfo(inputPath);
using (var p = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    var wb = p.Workbook;
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault() ?? wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

    var lastRow = ws.Dimension.Rows;
    for (var r = lastRow+1; r <= lastRow+50; r++)
    {
        for (var c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
        {
            ws.Cells[r, c].Value = $"{r}-{c}";
        }
    }

    p.Save();
}
```